# PrimeNG's data table not firing onRowSelect event

Tags: typescript, angular, primeng

I'm currently testing PrimeNG and trying to use the data table. Everything works fine, except for the events. I'm trying to use Growl to show a message when a row is selected(like the Events demo on the PrimeNG website).
I currently have this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataTable, Column, Schedule, Growl, Message } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { NameListService } from '../shared/index';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'dash',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['dashboard.component.css'],
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, DataTable, Column, Schedule]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  newName:string = '';
  newLanguage:string = '';
  errorMessage:string;
  names:any[] = [];
  selectedName:any;
  events:any[];
  cols:any[];
  msgs:Message[] = [];

  constructor(public nameListService:NameListService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getNames();
    this.cols = [
      {field: 'id', header: 'ID'},
      {field: 'name', header: 'Name'},
      {field: 'language', header: 'Language'}
    ];
}

  onRowSelect(event) {
    this.msgs = [];
    this.msgs.push({severity: 'info', summary: 'Selected', 
    detail:event.data.name + ' - ' + event.data.language});
}

  getNames() {
    this.nameListService.get()
      .subscribe(
        names => this.names = names,
    error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
);
  }

  addName():boolean {
    this.names.push({"name": this.newName, 
    "language": this.newLanguage});
    this.newName = '';
    this.newLanguage = '';
    return false;
  }

}
```

The dashboard component template looks like this:

```
<p-growl [value]="msgs"></p-growl>

<form (submit)="addName()" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newName" name="newName" 
     placeholder="Enter new name..."
     style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <label>Language:</label>
  <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newLanguage" 
     name="newLanguage" placeholder="Enter new language..."
     style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
         *ngIf="newName && newLanguage"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
</form>

<p-dataTable [value]="names" [(selection)]="selectedName" 
    selectionMode="single">
    <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" 
               [header]="col.header">
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>

<div *ngIf="selectedName">
  <label>Selected person name:</label><br/>
  <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedName? selectedName.name: none" 
     readonly style="margin-bottom: 10px;"/><br/>
  <label>Selected person programming language:</label><br/>
  <input class="form-control" 
     [(ngModel)]="selectedName? selectedName.language: none" 
     readonly style="margin-bottom: 10px;"/><br/>
  <label>Selected person birth year:</label><br/>
  <input class="form-control" 
     [(ngModel)]="selectedName? selectedName.birthYear: none" readonly/>
</div>
```

However, when I select a row the event doesn't fire. It doesn't stop at a breakpoint, so it doesn't register it at all. Is there a solution or some advice as to where I should look to fix this?

Comment: I don't find a place where you're firing `onRowSelect` method. Check my answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to specify `selectionMode`:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="names" selectionMode="single" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)">
  ...    
</p-dataTable>
```

valid values are "single" and "multiple"

**[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/1GOyUBV6HjDAAf48qH3U?p=preview)**

**Update:**

Also you have to subscribe on `onRowSelect` event

```
(onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
```

where

- `(onRowSelect)` - name of event from DataTable component
- `onRowSelect($event)` - name of method within your component

Answer (score -2):

You have to import FormsModule in your app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```